# mediaelement.js Fullscreen mode on Mac FF/Safari

Tags: mediaelement.js

at http://www.rocklobsterweb.de/soho/ the fullscreen mode is not working correct at "projekte" on Mac (Safari and Firefox). I am not sure if this is a problem of the mediaelements.js or the html/css container. I think it is the latter, because at "rolle" the "dummy"-film from John is running well in fullscreen.

Anyone any idea?

Thanks,
Jörgo

Thinking about changing to vimeo with the video files.